# How to prevent an Azure DevOps group admin inheriting the group restrictions

Tags: azure-devops

As an organisation and project admin I created a project Team and limited it to only see a single Area in a project. That works.

However, as I created the team I'm a member although I don't want to be. That means I inherit all the team's restrictions. Turning off inheritance in Area.Security doesn't work as it's not sticky, plus I don't want to turn off inheritance.

Is there a way to restrict a Team's access to work items using Area that doesn't involve losing all other project permissions for the team's admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, under:

> Organization Settings -> Users -> my_account -> Manage user

under that project my permissions were set to Custom for some reason. I changed it to Project Administrators for that project and now areas and teams work.

Comment: If your organization is connected to Microsoft Entra ID, you can enable auditing log to track changes that occur within your Azure DevOps organization. For example, permissions changes. See more info from [Access auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).